# Form block: how to choose which fields are being displayed?

Tags: 7, forms

I created a form block using the [form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module to allow users to post a certain content type and fill out the form without leaving the page. I don't remember how I chose which fields to show. Currently it only shows the title and the submit button but I would like to add another field and change the label of the button. Can I do that with this module and if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried going to the "Manage Display" of your certain content type?

Comment: Thanks sorry, I forgot to post my answer when I figured it out right after posting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to adjust custom [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) for the field I wanted to show and once I set the field permissions to "public" they showed. The permissions were under edit field in manage display of the content type.

I had originally looked in both permissions and in edit display.

[image]